ngIf deja espacios en blanco
tengo div con una directiva *ngFor donde muestra unos cards para mostrar productos pero si pongo la condicional de *ngIf para que los productos agotados no se muestren donde iria el card de ese producto queda el espacio en blanco
dejo el fragmento del codigo
<div class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="divContainer" *ngFor="let propiedad of propiedades | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 8, currentPage: page }">
            <div class="card" *ngIf="propiedad.mostrar">
            <!-- <div class="card"> -->
                <img src="https://marinoinmobiliaria.onrender.com/{{propiedad.imagen1}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p id="zonaCard">cod. {{propiedad.zona}} {{propiedad.codigo}}</p>
                    <h5 class="card-title">{{propiedad.tipoUnidad}} | {{propiedad.tipoOperacion}}</h5>
                    <p class="card-text">{{propiedad.tipoMoneda}}
                        {{propiedad.precio}}</p>
                    <p class="card-text d-xs-none line-clamp">{{propiedad.descripcion}}</p>
                    <a [routerLink]="['/detalle-prop', propiedad._id]" routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
                        class="btn btn-primary btnVerMas" (click)="verDetalles(propiedad._id)">Ver mas...</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>



Eso pasa porque se crea la columna pero el contenido no. Lo que se debe hacer es evitar crear la columna.
Para eso se puede usar ng-container para alojar el ngFor y colocar el ngIf en el div que lleva la columna:
<ng-container *ngFor="let propiedad of propiedades | paginate: { itemsPerPage: 8, currentPage: page }">
    <div *ngIf="propiedad.mostrar" class="col-xxl-3 col-xl-3 col-lg-4 col-md-4 col-xs-12" id="divContainer" >
                <div class="card" >
                <!-- <div class="card"> -->
                    <img src="https://marinoinmobiliaria.onrender.com/{{propiedad.imagen1}}" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <p id="zonaCard">cod. {{propiedad.zona}} {{propiedad.codigo}}</p>
                        <h5 class="card-title">{{propiedad.tipoUnidad}} | {{propiedad.tipoOperacion}}</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">{{propiedad.tipoMoneda}}
                            {{propiedad.precio}}</p>
                        <p class="card-text d-xs-none line-clamp">{{propiedad.descripcion}}</p>
                        <a [routerLink]="['/detalle-prop', propiedad._id]" routerLinkActive="router-link-active"
                            class="btn btn-primary btnVerMas" (click)="verDetalles(propiedad._id)">Ver mas...</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
</ng-container>

